# Mysql select distinct but count total repeated entries

Tags: mysql, subquery, distinct

I have a table with lots of duplicate records, I'm trying to count (summarized) how many duplicates there actual are and only show the unique combination .

i.e. the structure is as following :

```
id,name,category
```

Example of table data:

```
    id   name   category
    1    name1  category1 
    2    name1  category1
    3    name2  category2
    4    name2  category1
```

Now I am trying to generate output as following :

```
    name1 category1  2
    name2 category2  1
    name2 category1  1
```

What would be the best approach in achieving this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, category, COUNT(id) FROM people GROUP BY name, category
```

Comment: Thanks, I was messing around over complicating things with DISTINCT and subqueries. Much appreciated